# Is there a JSON library that can parse this value?

Tags: c#, json

```
[{\"Berth\":8,\"Name\":\"GROUP OF 8 (EIGHT)\",\"Cost\":1400.0000,\"BookingFee\":40.0000,\"Available\":true,\"ProductId\":49},{\"Berth\":6,\"Name\":\"GROUP OF 6 (SIX)\",\"Cost\":1050.0000,\"BookingFee\":30.0000,\"Available\":true,\"ProductId\":49},{\"Berth\":5,\"Name\":\"GROUP OF 5 (FIVE)\",\"Cost\":875.0000,\"BookingFee\":25.0000,\"Available\":true,\"ProductId\":49},{\"Berth\":4,\"Name\":\"GROUP OF 4 (FOUR)\",\"Cost\":700.0000,\"BookingFee\":20.0000,\"Available\":true,\"ProductId\":49},{\"Name\":\"CAMPING TICKET\",\"Cost\":135.0000,\"BookingFee\":5.0000,\"Available\":false,\"ProductId\":48},{\"Name\":\"WEEKENDER PASS\",\"Cost\":110.0000,\"BookingFee\":5.0000,\"Available\":false,\"ProductId\":50}]
```

That's it!

EDIT:

I wrapped the array in an object before serializing it and ran this code on the output...

```
            var prods = JsonValue.Parse(json).AsDynamic();

        var productId = prods.Products[0].ProductId;
```

And it just says that productid is 'Default'.

Comment: Is there something you have used that hasn't worked?

Comment: JsonValue, Json.net. I must be clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here isn't JSON and therefore can't be parsed. When you strip the slashes, however, you have valid JSON and can then parse it as normal.

EDIT:

I think what you want to do is this:

```
prods[0].ProductId
```

prods is an array, not an object.

Can you show the code where you "wrapped the array in an object" - because it sounds like that's where your problem lies.

Comment: I'm using JavaScriptSerializer to serialize and its adding quotes around the whole object and then escaping the quotes for each property/value. Should it be doing this?

Comment: Nah... what I was doing was correct. I should have mentioned that when wrapping the array in an object I assigned it to a property called 'Products'. I thought that would have been straight forward to see but I guess it was just a bit sloppy of me. Anyhow... you were right, there were too many escaped quotes because I was serializing the object *twice*. Once with 'JavaScriptSerializer' and then it was doing it behind the scenes when creating an MVC 'JsonResult'. Big duh for me... its not surprising all the Json libraries became useless. :)